# how to replicate input file fields

Tags: javascript, html

I've a table named 'pedidos' and a table named 'locais'. For each 'pedidos' there can be several 'locais'. So I'm using this form

[image: form]

In the right column I want the user to type the data for each 'locais' which includes an image file. Then when the user clicks on 'Acrescentar Local' the table on the left is being filled. But instead off adding the image as well  it loses the file.

I'm using the code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href= "redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script language="javascript">
    var a=0;
    var clone = [];
    function addLoc()
    {
    /*  var tmp = jQuery('#foto').clone();
        clone.push(tmp[0]);*/



        /*document.getElementById('loc_table').innerHTML+="<tr><td>"+document.getElementById('local').value+"</td><td>"+document.getElementById('comp').value+"</td><td>"+document.getElementById('larg').value+"</td><td>"+clone[a]+"</td></tr>";*/


        document.getElementById('loc_table').innerHTML+="<tr><td>"+document.getElementById('local').value+"</td><td>"+document.getElementById('comp').value+"</td><td>"+document.getElementById('larg').value+"</td><td><input type='file' id='foto"+a+"'/></td></tr>";
        document.getElementById('foto'+a)=document.getElementById('foto');


        a++;
    /*
    "+document.getElementById('foto').value+"</td></tr>";
    */

    }
    </script>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <form id='addPed' name='addPed' action='#' method='POST'>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="nome">nome</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="nome" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td><label for="desc">descricao</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="desc" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td><label for="datai">data de insercao</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="datai" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td><label for="datae">data de entrega</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="date" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Adicionar pedido"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    LOCAIS:
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <table id="loc_table">
    <tr>
    <td class="tableheader">local</td>
    <td class="tableheader">comprimento</td>
    <td class="tableheader">largura</td>
    <td class="tableheader">foto</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   <!-- </form> -->
    </td>
    <td>
    <!-- <form id='addLoc' name='addPed' action='#' method='POST'> -->
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="local">local</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="local" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td><label for="comp">comprimento</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="comp" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td><label for="larg">largura</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="larg" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td><label for="foto">foto</label></td>
    <td><input type="file" id="foto" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Acrescentar Local" onclick="addLoc()"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Can Anyone sugest me a solution please!

Thanks

Comment: You're losing the file because your code `.innerHTML+=..` is overwriting your existing HTML with a new HTML string. You need to manually add elements to the DOM instead here.

Comment: Try removing the `action="#"` from the `form` element.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, with your sugestion I can add the elements and with each new element I don't lose previous files, althought when I click 'Acrescentar local' the file selected in the form doesn't go to the table, so I've got to select the file in the table again. Any way to transfer the file from the form to the table?